# Connecting 2 vm having ubuntu on same device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, vmware, connectivity

I have a window laptop where i have installed 2 ubuntu VM's on VMWARE workstation 17 player. I have downloaded apache on one Virtual machine and DNS on the other. I have a website on ubuntu having apache. I want to connect the two virtual machines so i can access the website from the other virtual machine having DNS.

Comment: Have you configured Apache or your DNS service? Do they work - how did you test them? What have you tried in evidence that you cannot already access the website from the DNS server?

Comment: i have already configured both dns and apache and tested themand they work. I have tried making a zone in dns to give the site ip  , but everytime the dns fails when i restart bind9

Comment: sorry i am new to linux and ubuntu  so i dont have much knowledge  so i came to this exchange in hope i will find some help.

Comment: my VM's have NAT connection

Comment: `my VM's have NAT connection` well you'll need bridged or host-only.

Comment: what OS is vmware workstation running on?  Windows? If so, this probably belongs on https://superuser.com/, not here.  This seems to be mostly a network & ip forwarding or routing configuration detail on the HOST system, which is not something that the ubuntu guests have any control over.

Comment: "_i have already configured both dns and apache and tested themand they work_" but also "_the dns fails when i restart `bind9`_" - in that case the DNS server clearly does not work. That needs to be resolved but we can't help unless you provide details in your question

Comment: but now i need some more help     as i can access the website made in apache ubuntu from the ubuntu vm having bind. i can open site using ip and domain name but when i do nslookup for the website is says NXDOMAIN . dig command also shows no answer like ip adderess

Comment: thanks for the help guys

Comment: Unless you provide concrete examples no-one is going to be able to give you concrete answers